# Converting one sentence to a certain template - NLP

Tags: nlp, similarity

I just started learning NLP in order to achieve something. I'm running through the very basics currently. But I was curious to know if the following is possible and what is the name of the technique for it

What I want is let's say I have few commands like 'open chrome' or 'open mozilla'. A user may type naturally, 'I want you to open chrome'. Is it possible to convert the input to a fixed template. The reason being, I might write functions for each template I have. Converting the template will help me know what program the user wants to open by looking at its second word.

Comment: You might use from the Stanford CoreNLP the [TokensRegex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.html). You can apply a label for every matching pattern and take action according to that label.

Comment: A POS tagger is a good place to start, though you may find this problem to be far less tractable than it appears.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few research articles about taking some natural language text and then matching that text against one or more question templates.

Here is the approach as I see it.

First take your natural language text and convert that natural language text into one or more tokens of interest. A token might be a string representing an e-mail address, or it might be a verb, or it might be a number. You will need to pick some NLP system, simple or advanced, that takes text and spits out such tokens.  You can even code a trivial tagging system yourself to get started, and then replace a trivial tagger with something better later.

Now think of there being a set of question templates, where each question templates consists of one or more slots. Each slot is associated with one or more predicates, where each predicate is of the form p(token). A token will only match a slot if that token satisfies all the predicates of that slot.

Now do this...

```
   for each question template A in the set of question templates
    begin
      for each slot S in question template A
        begin
         for each token T in the set of input tokens generated by your tagger
                attempt to bind that token T to S.
                A binding only takes place if all p(T) = true
                      for each predicate p of that slot S.
         end  
      if all slots are bound to a token, generate a query from
         the question template A given the bindings of slots to tokens
     end
```

Since this processing above may yield more than one query, you must devise a ranking scheme of some kind to pick the top query.

Note that the means to generate a query can be as simple as substituting values in the tokens in some query template such as "select * from ${table}". Or you can associate each question template with some method that will generate a query for that question template with its slots bound to tokens.

One of the challenges here is making the predicates smart enough. For example, a predicate looking for the word "links" might also accept the word "connects" or "associated".

While this kind of question template approach has real limitations, it has advantages too. The approach can be useful in restricted domains where there are limited number of questions that users may ask. Think somewhere up to a hundred or two hundred questions.

In such situations, it can be a *lot* easier to fit the text that users enter to a relatively small set of question templates, rather than tackle much harder problems about truly understanding a question, and mapping that question to a query (or a command).

My description focused on queries, but the same approach works for commands too. doesn't make much of a difference.

Others, at Google, Facebook and IBM (Watson) have deeper approaches. I greatly admire their work, but for folks working in a narrow domain, question template approaches are worth a look.

There are not, however, as far as I know, any decent open source solutions for such a question template approach.  At this point, it appears that you have to build your own solution.

Comment: Is it possible to share a link to a related paper or publication mentioning or introducing the terms in much more detail?